# JavaScript function not being called for some reason

Tags: javascript, function

I am baffled as to why it is not going into the function.  At first, I thought it was maybe it was getting hung up on the innerHTML stuff, but that can't be it, as it's not even going into the function.   I know it's the code below that's at fault, not the pages in the iframe source as they work just fine, that the problem is happening.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setFrameContent(num){



window.alert("Ow!");

if (num == 1)
{

 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "
<iframe src='./cosTweets1.html' style='width: 1000px; height: 190px;'></iframe>";


}

else if (num == 2)
{

 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "
<iframe src='./cosTweets2.html' style='width: 1000px; height: 190px;'></iframe>";

}


}
</script>
</head>
<body>




<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 1000px; background-color: blue;">
<button id="b1" value="1" style="width: 90px;"  onclick="setFrameContent(1)"> 1</button>   
<button id="b2" value="2" style="width: 90px;" onclick="setFrameContent(2)"> 2</button>
<button id="b3" value="3" style="width: 90px;"> 3</button>
<button id="b4" value="4" style="width: 90px;"> 4</button>
<button id="b5" value="5" style="width: 90px;"> 5</button>
<button id="b6" value="6" style="width: 90px;"> 6</button>
<button id="b7" value="7" style="width: 90px;"> 7</button>
<button id="b8" value="8" style="width: 90px;"> 8</button>
<button id="b9" value="9" style="width: 90px;"> 9</button>
<button id="b10" value="10" style="width: 90px;"> 10</button>

</div>

<div id="div1" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 1000px;">

<iframe src="./cosTweets1.html" style="width: 1000px; height: 190px;"></iframe>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Strangely enough, this other code below I was working on, for another thing, did work, so it cannot be that I just passed it a number that is causing the issue.

```
<html>
<head><title> SPRBC Events Demo </title>

<style>

p { font-size: 2.5em;}
</style>
<script>

var array = ["Bla bla bla", "Yak yak yak", "Mongoose", "We need more funds!"];


function changeText(index)
{

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 

array[index];

}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="p1" > So frustrating! </p>

<a href="#" onclick="changeText(0)">Click</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeText(1)">Click</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeText(2)">Click</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeText(3)">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make a fiddle.

Comment: I agree on takendarkk. You must at least make a fiddle for it.

Comment: What is supposed to be working, how, but isn't? I see nothing but code here, I don't get your point.

Comment: `<script>`'s will be parsed completely(no matter if they will be executed or not). When the parser detects a syntax-error the entire `<script>` will be discarded. Your console should have noticed the syntax-error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript can't be more than one line, but arrays can. That's why your first code sample doesn't work and your second one does.

Use

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<iframe src='./cosTweets1.html' style='width: 1000px; height: 190px;'></iframe>";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<iframe src='./cosTweets2.html' style='width: 1000px; height: 190px;'></iframe>";
```